# Generic method with class & new() keyword

Tags: c#

```
 public class ViewModelBaseEx<T> : ViewModelBase where T : class, new()
 {
      //...........
 }
```

I found a class like this in a sample. In this class what is the meaning of portion **"where T : class, new()"**. what is the use of class, new() in this method definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that `T` must be a reference type (normally a `class`, `interface`, `delegate` or array) (but not a `struct`) and that it must have a public parameterless constructor `T()` (so this will rule out all the previous with exception of `class`).

Comment: Other reference types that are OK with the `: class` constraint (but which cannot be used with the `: new()` constraint) are interfaces (for example `ICloneable`) and array types (like `int[]`).

Answer (score 7):

It is a generic type constraint.

It specifies that whatever `T` is, it must be a reference type (a `class`) and it must have a public default parameterless constructor (`new()`).

This allows people to do this:

```
var x = new T();
```

Without the `new()` constraint, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `class, new()` are adding constraints.

**class** means that it should be of type class (structs etc are not allowed)

**new()** represents that it must have a public constructor which takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `T` must be a reference (class) type and that it must also have a public default constructor.

See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

class here is to constraint T to be of Class only, i.e, cannot be structure and other value types.

new() here is to constraint T has to have an empty constructor.

for more information on type constraint, look at the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score -1):

"class" basically means that "T" is a class type (could be a struct as well => primitive type). The "new()" syntax means that "T" is a class that has an empty constructor so in your class you could do something like:

```
var obj = new T();
```

Comment: I think think is confusing. `class` doesn't mean the type has to be a class (as other answers explain). And `struct`s aren't just the primitive types (as they are usually understood), they are also types like `Guid`.